# Why does this table-cell overlap the table-cell adjacent to it?

Tags: css, css-position, css-tables

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jxwudoe7/)**

This is an SSCCE demonstrating a div with display:table with three child divs having a display:table-cell. The problem is that the .blog-post-slide overlaps the .previous-slide-arrow, rather than being adjacent to it.

The question is why, and how should I solve this problem.

```css
.post-main-area {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.post-main-area .previous-slide-arrow,
.post-main-area .next-slide-arrow {
  border: 5px solid green;
  /*check*/
  width: 5%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 20px;
}
.post-main-area .next-slide-arrow {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
.post-slide {
  border: 5px solid wheat;
  /*check*/
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-main-area">
  <a class="previous-slide-arrow" href="#">&lt;</a>

  <div class="post-slide">.
    <!--<div class="left-part">.</div>
   <div class="right-part">.</div>-->
  </div>

  <a class="next-slide-arrow" href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you shift the first cell 20px to the right:

```css
position: relative;
left: 20px;
```

Then, as explained in [Relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning), it overlaps the following cell.

> Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated,
>   it may be shifted relative to this position. This is called *relative
>   positioning*. Offsetting a box (B1) in this way has no effect on the
>   box (B2) that follows: B2 is given a position as if B1 were not offset
>   and B2 is not re-positioned after B1's offset is applied. This implies
>   that relative positioning may cause boxes to overlap.

Instead, I would add some margin to the table:

```css
width: calc(100% - 40px);
margin: 0 20px;
```

```css
.post-main-area {
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.post-main-area .previous-slide-arrow,
.post-main-area .next-slide-arrow {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 5%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-slide {
  border: 5px solid wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-main-area">
  <a class="previous-slide-arrow" href="#">&lt;</a>
  <div class="post-slide">.</div>
  <a class="next-slide-arrow" href="#">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't manually move the buttons and stuff, try adding display:table-cell; to .post-slide {} and getting rid of all of the left: and right: attributes like so;

```
.post-main-area {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.post-main-area .previous-slide-arrow,
.post-main-area .next-slide-arrow {
  border: 5px solid green;
  /*check*/
  width: 5%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.post-slide {
  border: 5px solid wheat;
  display: table-cell;
  /*check*/
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
```

This allows the computer to position everything like a table, and due to the widths and the order you write the elements in the html document, it should work.